# how to give the textbox component the code editor style? WinUI 3

Tags: windows, xaml, winui-3, winui

I am creating a notes app to practice WinUI, and I would like to give it Markdown qualities, so I want to split the window between the MD code and the other side of the text with MD styles applied.

for now I am using the textbox component and it looks like notepad but I would like to add highlights like the code editors, is this possible? how can I achieve this?

This is the code I'm using today and it gives me the look of notepad text input

```
<TextBox
    AutomationProperties.Name="multi-line TextBox"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    BorderThickness="0"
    FontSize="24"
    FontFamily="consola"
    Background="Transparent"
    IsSpellCheckEnabled="True">
        <TextBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundFocused" Color="Transparent" />
        </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your `TextBlock` programmatically like this.

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="Click" />
    <TextBlock
        x:Name="MarkdownTextBlock"
        Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MarkdownTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run()
    {
        Text = "Title",
        FontSize = 28,
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
        Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue)
    });
    this.MarkdownTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
    this.MarkdownTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run()
    {
        Text = "Message",
    });
}
```

In case you just want a Markdown control, you can use the [MarkdownTextBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/markdowntextblock) from the CommunityToolkit.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I meant more in the textbox component to add the line number and change the font size if it is h1 or h2 or h3, that kind of styling in the component

Comment: Sorry. I thought you wanted to implement that part yourself. I updated my answer. You can use the ``MarkdownTextBlock`` or take a look the source code to see how it's implemented.

Comment: I didn't know that could work there too, amazing I will try it, thank you very much @Andrew_KeepCoding